# Usable field type for date of birth on devices

Tags: responsive-design, multiple-devices

I have a question about what kind of form input needs to be used to provide the best experience for date of birth field on mobile devices..I have tried to  use the device specific native spinners. The spinners work fine for recent dates but I find that thry are cumbersome to use if your date of birth is somewhere in the 70s.the spinner needs to be spun a lot to reach that year...Any suggestions on how to better design that field from a usability perspective would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think the spinner is causing effort for users, then you can use a spinner for scoped number of options like the month (max 12), but allow a user to type for the date and year. You just would have to do the added work of coding the checks to only allow *valid* numerical values. So watch out for February (29) vs. September (30) and the year.

Alternatively, you could get a sense of the average age of your users and set that as the default year for less physical scrolling on the screen. So set the year to 1985 and 1970 isn't much further away, but neither is 1995. My caution with this would be, you may be throwing users off since doing this is non-standard. There is such a thing as cognitive load, that even if you are creating less clicks or screen interaction, you may be asking your users to think harder about what they're doing. Let us know what you go with!